# Trying to solve a shutil.error in my Python code

Tags: python, file, error-handling, shutil, try-except

This is my first post.
I need help solving shutil.Error in my Python code.
I'm making a program (for study purposes) that checks a dir, detects if a file is duplicated (based in its hashed contents), and moves them into a new folder.
In previous code, i defined everything, but in this section im having problems.

```
if file!=keep and keep!=str(0):
    print("Moving files", file)
    shutil.move(file,p)
    cont=0  
    try:
        f=Path(file)
        safecopy=f.with_stem(f.stem + "(Copy "+ str(cont) + ")")
        f.rename(safecopy)
        shutil.move(f,p)
        cont += 1
    except shutil.Error:
        pass



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Workspace\WORK\TEST-copy.py", line 117, in <module>
    dupfolder()
  File "c:\Workspace\WORK\TEST-copy.py", line 91, in dupfolder
    shutil.move(file,p)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 804, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:\Workspace\TestFolder\duplicate\thething - b428efd16f0ef658bdce633abf747ce7\code(Copy 0).doc' already exists
```

I need some kind of loop to generate the copies.
In safecopy i tried to define the new name of the file.
Any idea will be useful, im kind of new with programming!

Thanks

Edit 1: My "try" isn't aplying because the program ends with the shutil.Error.
The file DOES exist.

Edit 2: Solved! Replaced for except OSError:

Comment: The error says that the file already exists. Can you confirm it's not the case?

Comment: @pavel You are right, the file does exist. But my "try" isn't aplying because the program ends with the shutil.Error

Comment: Not sure what's happening here, seems like you're catching a correct exception. Try catching `OSError` and/or `ValueError` which `shutil.Error` is likely a subclass of.

Comment: Also try catching `Error` (without "shutil ")

Comment: Well @pavel, now i can apply my "try" and i can catch the error. THANKS!
Edit: But in mutiple files with the same name, it generates "namefile (copy 0)" and replaces the file in the target duplicate path. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I can't see the loop that executes here so I don't really know how it's going to work with multiple files.

Comment: @pavel i solved it! Thank you for your help!